# Make instance accessible by only one thread at the time?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a java class:

```
class Card {

  private static Card instance = new Card();
  public int value:

  private Card() {}

  public static Card sharedInstange() {
     return instance;
  }

}
```

This class models a shared instance which can be access by different threads. The instance variable value therefor must be synchronized such that only one thread can read and write it at a time.

**How can I achieve that my instance variables of the Card class can only accessed by one thread at the time?**

Edit: Here is the same class with getter and setter.

```
class Card {

  private static Card instance = new Card();
  private int value:

  private Card() {}

  public static Card sharedInstange() {
     return instance;
  }

  public int getValue() { return value; }

  public void setValue(int v) { this.value = v; }

}
```

Comment: Could you do a search on the site? I don't feel like answering this *again*.

Comment: synchronized (instance) { ... } possibly?

Comment: are you looking for a singleton instance?

Comment: @AnantLaxmikantBobde Doesn't look like it. *How can I achieve that my instance variables of the Card class can only accessed by one thread at the time*

Comment: You might want to check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it volatile and create getters/setters without synchronized keyword.

Or just make it `AtomicInteger`.